# node.js terminal error. (MAC)

Tags: node.js, macos

I've downloaded node.js and have already checked if it's installed by typing `node -v`into the terminal. I already found a question which was almost the same as mine, but their answer didn't work at all.

Anyways, my problem is that I can't get .js files to open with node.js. When I type `node automatic.js` it responds with this (I put #FULLNAME instead of my actual full name):

```
Maxs-MBP-2:desktop #FULLNAME#$ node automatic.js
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './app/logging.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/#FULLNAME#/Desktop/automatic.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

I'm sorry if this is actually an easy fix, I'm new to all of this. This is also my first post on Stackoverflow. Hello, world! Thank you so much!

~Max

Comment: The error means `./app/logging.js` does not exist.

Comment: Wait, what? I downloaded everything, so why doesn't it exist? I followed the config instructions perfectly. Am I not doing the right command? Sorry, I just don't know why it wouldn't exist.